# Using Hibernate, how do I get access to stored procedure return codes?

Tags: sql, hibernate, stored-procedures, return-value

Using Hibernate, I have successfully called stored procedures and gotten the data using the "getResultList()" method. However, SQL Server (and probably other SQL implementations) allow you to declare a variable to hold return codes as shown below:

```
DECLARE @return_code int;  
EXECUTE @return_code = my_proc;
SELECT @return_code AS return_code;
```

How do I declare and access such a variable using Hibernate's stored procedure API?

Here is an example of the test procedure & the results that I'd like returned to me using Hibernate:
[StoredProcedureTestResultExpectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWOvK.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are speaking about stered *precedure* and not about a *function*?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's definitely a stored procedure. In fact, that code template is being used in our production systems, written in php. I've been tasked with rewriting it & I've chosen Spring/Hibernate for the new implementation. In the example, my_proc represents the stored procedure. Here is the php query string that I'm trying to replace with Hibernate code:  `code`$sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON; DECLARE @ReturnValue int; EXEC @ReturnValue = $name $paramStr; SELECT @ReturnValue as ReturnValue;";